# Triple slash references appearing in automatically generated declaration source files

Tags: typescript

I am writing a library that internally uses jquery, but the library's API does not expose any jquery types.

The typescript compiler is generating a declaration file for my library which includes a /// reference to the DefinitelyTyped ambient declaration file for jquery. Is this normal behaviour? Is there any way to disable it?

I feel like the jquery declaration file reference should only be copied into the generated declaration file if some jquery types are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. As an additional note. External definitions, I.e. definitions in *.d.ts are never copied to output (opposed to definitions in .ts file). You can always rename .d.ts to .ts if you want them copied.